Existence of a commutator whose $p$-th power is in the commutator subgroup
For an associative ring $A$, let $[A, A]$ to be the subgroup generated by $\{ xy-yx: x, y \in A\}$.
$\textbf{My question:}$ For $A = \mathbb{Z}\{X, Y\}$, does there exist a non-zero $ \alpha \in [A, A]$ and a prime $p$ such that $\alpha^p \in [A, A]?$
I have tried with $p=2, 3$ and with some examples. But I coudn't settle this.
Fact from Hesselholt's paper: If $S$ is a totally order poset, $A=\mathbb{Z}\{S\}$, then followings are true.
(1) two words are conjugate iff their difference is a commutator.
(2) $A/[A,A]$ is free abelian group generated by circular words in $S$.
(3) An element $\alpha $ of $A$ belongs to $[A,A]$ iff lexocographically least element of $\alpha$ (which is additive) is zero.

This is not the best notation. Usually [A,A] is the ideal generated by the commutators.

I agree with you, but the paper I have cited above uses this notation. That's why I went for it.
